# Schedule local notification every x day of the week - React native & Firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase` to schedule local notifications every day at a certain time. However, I would like to allow the user to decide when to receive the notifications in a given week.

For example, he could set notifications from Monday to Friday and not receive any on Saturday and Sunday. Currently, I am only able to set a `repeatInterval` property to `'day'` but am struggling to implement the mentioned feature. Any ideas?

(Yes, this could be done with FCM and a server, I am just asking if this is possible locally in RN)

Comment: You'll need to schedule 7 different weekly notifications that each can be turned on and off since the `repeatInterval` is a fixed value.

Comment: Yeah so `repeatInterval: 'week'` for each day of the week. I thought about this but thought it was a bit messy.

Comment: Yeah exactly. It's a bit messy to be sure but I don't think there's another way given the constraints of the fixed-interval alarm system and no way to bail out of triggering a notification at runtime.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for helping me out :) will do it this way then!